# Is this possible to get UWP print cancel event and printer UI close event in code behind

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, uwp-xaml

My Requirement in UWP app.

1. I want to show a message after when the printer UI closed.
2. Also, I want some notification when we click to cancel the printer

   ```
   await PrintManager.ShowPrintUIAsync();
   ```

Comment: what problem  are you facing?

Answer (score 1):

The `PrintManager.ShowPrintUIAsync` does not return the result of printing nor if the printing was successful. It just returns `true` or `false` whether the print dialog was successfully shown.

To achieve you requirements, you will have to use the `PrintTask.Completed` event and its `EventArgs` instance to know if the user successfully printed or canceled the print.

To be able to print, you are surely handling the `PrintManager.PrintTaskRequested` event. This is where you create the `PrintTask` and where you can set its `Completed` handler:

```
protected virtual void PrintTaskRequested(PrintManager sender, PrintTaskRequestedEventArgs e)
{
   PrintTask printTask = null;
   printTask = e.Request.CreatePrintTask("C# Printing SDK Sample", sourceRequested =>
   {
         // Print Task event handler is invoked when the print job is completed.
         printTask.Completed += async (s, args) =>
         {
            //was print task canceled?
            if (args.Completion == PrintTaskCompletion.Canceled)
            {
               await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
               {
                   MessageDialog dlg = new MessageDialog( "Printing canceled" );
                   dlg.ShowAsync();
               });
            }
         };

         sourceRequested.SetSource(printDocumentSource);
   });
}
```

More details on printing in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/print-from-your-app).

Please note that we are using `PrintTaskCompletion.Canceled` to check if the `Completion` of the print task was a cancel. Also note, that the `Completed` event handler is not running on the UI thread, so you have to use `Dispatcher` to run code on the UI thread.